# React native pdf in webview only showing the first page

Tags: react-native, expo

Fetching base64 from an api that i Render in WebView (expo project)

Upon rendering object and iframe inside of webview I get the needed pdf but I can only see the first page without the ability of scrolling through pages

```js
 <WebView
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
          scrollEnabled={false}
            source={{
              html: `\
              <div style="display:flex;height:100%">
              <object style="margin:auto" width data="data:application/pdf;base64, ${pdf64}" type="application/pdf">
                <iframe style="width:'100%;height:100%" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?&embedded=true"></iframe>
            </object>
             </div>
        `,
            }}
          />
```

This is the current code which is kind of working

Answer (score 0):

Please try wrapping your code within a `ScrollView` to make the content visible/scrollable. See below example for reference

```
const [pdfData, setPdfData] = useState("");
let image = "data:application/pdf;base64, ${yourPdfBase64}";
setPdfData(image);

<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <WebView
            useWebKit={true}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
            source={{
               html: `
            <html>
            <object data="${pdfData}" type="application/pdf">
                <embed 
                    scrollbar="1" 
                    src="${pdfData}" 
                    type="application/pdf" 
                   
                />
            </object>
            </html>
           `}}
        />
   </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```